# How to get rid of Console warning "in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.google.android.gms.unstable" when running Flutter App to Bluestacks?

Tags: android, flutter, bluestacks

This issue is happening only when Im running flutter app using BlueStacks as emulator.
I did create the very basic Flutter app just to make sure that is not because of packages. And yes on the plain flutter app it shows this error. Its not showing when using Emulator from Android Studio

```
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.google.android.gms.unstable
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236): Process: com.google.android.gms.unstable, PID: 10236
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236): java.lang.AssertionError: MalformedURLException for the URL
> 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidantiabuse/v1/x/create?alt=PROTO&key=AIzaSyBofcZsgLSS7BOnBjZPEkk4rYwzOIz-lTI'
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at rnh.ax(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):4)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at uhs.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):1)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at uhu.a(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):10)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.DroidGuardChimeraService.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):11)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at dsm.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):1)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at put.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@214218022@21.42.18
> (040700-410302452):4)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3194)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1570)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10236):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
>     E/AndroidRuntime(10266): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.google.android.gms.unstable
```

My Flutter Doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[√] Connected device (6 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: also I am facing this issue. it is not only happen with flutter also java

Comment: This is about google play services in the emulator, use an emulator that has google play services.

Comment: BlueStacks does actually have Google play services

Comment: what's the SDK version on BlueStack? try 21 or higher.

Comment: I'm currently using the latest Bluestack 5. Android version Nougat 7.1.2 SDK 25

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is you key in the following correct? It can be caused by cases when you have *invisible characters*.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(10236): java.lang.AssertionError: MalformedURLException for the URL
'https://www.googleapis.com/androidantiabuse/v1/x/create?alt=PROTO&key=AIzaSyBofcZsgLSS7BOnBjZPEkk4rYwzOIz-lTI'
```

Secondly, if it is only a warning and nothing serious happens (i.e. your app behaves normally), you may safely ignore it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer.

1st). I didnt key in any information. As I've mentioned I duplicate the error with the basic default flutter app so I didn't even touch the codebase and still this issue is showing.
2nd). This error is fine if it didnt obscure some important warning and error thats also showing on the console. It appears randomly and frequently and sometimes in a loop. That I even have to scroll looongg way down the console just to see my print statement.

Comment: @DavidB. then you can just suppress the error, i.e. forbid it from appearing.